# Go through all available variants in Shopify liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to show all the available sizes from a product in the collection page.
I managed to write this snippet that will show available sizes, but only for one of the color combinations.

```
             {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
                {% assign downcased_option = option.name | downcase %}
                  {% if downcased_option contains 'size' %}
                    {% assign is_size = true %}
                    {% for value in option.values %}
                      {% assign variant_available = true %}
                      {% if product.options.size >= 1 %}
                        {% unless product.variants[forloop.index0].available  %}
                          {% assign variant_available = false %}
                        {% endunless %}
                      {% endif %}
                      <span class="{% unless variant_available %}soldout{% endunless %}">{{ value | escape }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
```

But, let's say we have the next variants:

*Green/32, Green/34
Blue/34
Black/34, Black/36*

With the snippet above, it will not show available size 36 from black color as it's not available in green.

What I want is to go through every single size and show if availability, no matter the color.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm missing something but making the assumption that all variants have a size and there are only two options you just need to loop through the available variants and just display the variant name split it and display first or last where ever the size is in the options list. if there are loads of duplicates then put them in an array and run 'uniq'.

```
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
        {% if variant.available %}
          {% assign sizesList = variant.title | split: '/' | first | append: ', ' }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% assign sizes = sizesList | split: ', ' %}
      {{ sizes | uniq | join: ", " }}
```